# Google Sheets Filter Date Greater Than Cell

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to set a filter on my data that the dates that show up are greater than the date in a cell. In my worksheet the "Start Date" is in I1. My filter is off column "Date" which contains a series of dates:

[image]

I've tried =I1 and =date(I1) but nothing seems to work here.

**How can I filter dates newer than the value of a cell?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `=L$1` in that field, with absolute reference in the row number.

Explanation: if the reference is relative, `=L1`, then only the first data cell in the filtered range (e.g., A2) will actually be compared to L1. The cell A3 will be compared to L2, A4 to L3, and so on.

By the way, instead of "date is after", "exact date", "cell reference", it's a little easier to use "greater than", "cell reference". One fewer dropdown to deal with.

Comment: Good advice and great answer!